# Chinese characters for "bu da jie" meaning unrelated

Tags: character-identification

Can someone assist with providing the correct Chinese characters for the saying "bu da jie" which means unrelated.

This saying appears in the Suzhou dialect so it is quite common in our household, but I don't know how to write this.

Comment: 不搭界 (literal translation: not reaching the boundary)

Comment: Yes, it should be 不搭界. I remember in Suzhou dialect, this word sounds like "fu da ga".

Comment: @Huang - yes, quite similar to that

Comment: @Huang That's the pervasive pronunciation in most of the Wu dialects.

Comment: I, as someone from Northern China, have used this term very frequently, although I tend to pronounce it as 'bu da ga'. I always thought it as a slang derived from Beijing dialect. It is interesting to know it actually came from Wu dialects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

不搭界 (bùdājiè in Mandarin) is a common informal expression in Wu dialects (which include Shanghainese and the Suzhou dialect). Its literal meaning, as indicated in the comments, refers to 'not having a common boundary'. In current usage, it refers to two matters, objects or people having no shared connection or relationship.

An example, of two people quarrelling:

> A: 阿拉从此浑身不搭界！
>   B: 随便侬！
>
> A: We don't have anything to do with each other from now on! (lit: We from now on are unrelated all over the body)
>   B: Whatever! (Lit: “Do as you wish”)